# При предположительном вычитании, значение x1 не меняется

Tags: c#

только начал c# изучать, и уже столкнулся с проблемой, вроде вычитаю x2 от x1, но x1 не меняется
,вот код:

```
using System;

    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите два целых числа через пробел"); 
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] splitString = line.Split(' ');

            int x1 = int.Parse(splitString[0]);
            int x2 = int.Parse(splitString[1]);

            int sum = x1+=x2; 
            int difference = x1=x1-x2; 
            int multiply = x1*=x2; 
            Console.WriteLine($"{sum} {difference} {multiply}"); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: не знаком с с шарп, но предполагаю что ошибка в int sum = x1+=x2; 
вы сначала х1 увеличивает на значение х2. А уже потом пытаетесь отнять. 
int sum = x1+x2; <- вот так попробуйте

Comment: Поддержу,  поправьте int sum = x1+x2;
Также обратите внимание, что   int difference = x1=x1-x2; в difference  передается то же значение, что будет записано в x1. 
Не пытайтесь использовать синтаксический сахар, если не до конца его понимаете. Для вас самого, код становится менее понятным, а компилятору всё равно, как записано выражение

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = x1+=x2; 
// sum == x1 == x1 + x2;
int difference = x1=x1-x2; 
// difference == x1 - x2, но x1 == x1 + x2, поэтому x1 == x1 (изначальному)
```

Не пишите так. Вы потом сами запутаетесь, особенно если Вы новичек. Вместо sum = x1+=x2 -> sum = x1 + x2, difference = x1=x1-x2 -> difference = x1 - x2;